# XSLT template to output child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with XSLT and need help. I replaced my original post with this one.
I have an XML file with an empty element that I eventually want to expand using content from a second XML file. I am using the `xsltproc` (XSLT 1.0) for my processing engine on Ubuntu.

I noticed the Identity Template is not copying the DOCTYPE from the input, if it is supposed to.

I created a simplified test input file and simplified XSLT file.  I still cannot get the "genres" XSLT Template to do anything.  I changed that template to remove the named element - but it does not do that.

New Input XML -

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE tellico PUBLIC '-//Robby Stephenson/DTD Tellico V11.0//EN' 'http://periapsis.org/tellico/dtd/v11/tellico.dtd'>

<tellico xmlns="http://periapsis.org/tellico/" syntaxVersion="11">
      <collection title="My Videos" type="3">

<entry id="1002">
<title>Midsomer Murders -- Set 25</title>
<id>1002</id>
<comments>Includes bonus material</comments>
<year>2013</year>
<cover>file:///data/www/htdocs/videodb/cache/img/1002.jpg</cover>
<running-time>90</running-time>
<medium>DVD</medium>
<genres></genres>
<set>Yes</set>
<count>3</count>
<location>2</location>
</entry>

</collection>
</tellico>
```

New XSLT Transform file -

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- the identity template (copies your input verbatim) -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special templates only for things that need them -->
  <xsl:template match="genres"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Process command:

```html
xsltproc -o merged.xml --novalid Identity.xslt test-input-merge.xml
```

I have to use the --novalid option because the periapsis.org site is down at this time.

And the output I get is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tellico xmlns="http://periapsis.org/tellico/" syntaxVersion="11">
      <collection title="My Videos" type="3">

<entry id="1002">
<title>Midsomer Murders -- Set 25</title>
<id>1002</id>
<comments>Includes bonus material</comments>
<year>2013</year>
<cover>file:///data/www/htdocs/videodb/cache/img/1002.jpg</cover>
<running-time>90</running-time>
<medium>DVD</medium>
<genres/>
<set>Yes</set>
<count>3</count>
<location>2</location>
</entry>

</collection>
</tellico>
```

According to the XSLT transform, and my limited understanding - the "genres" element should have not been included in the output, but it is.  This is just a test, for now, to try and figure out how to get the genres template to do something.

I hope this improves on my original post and someone sees what is wrong. 
Thanks to all for any help you can provide.

Comment: You wrote: "expand the element". Which element would you like to expand and how? What this "expansion" actually means?

Comment: My original post had text giving element names that was not accepted, edited the post to place element names in quotes. - sorry, I'm new to this forum.

Comment: Got it to work by removing the DOCTYPE entry and attributes on the initial "tellico" element from the input XML file.  Now I can move on to the processing I really want to happen - add child elements from another XML file to the "genres" element.  I will no-doubt need help with that too.  THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `match="entry[genres]"` isn't matching the `entry` element, but it's wrong anyway. What you need is something like:

```
<xsl:template match="genres">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document($with)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I changed the xsl:template for genres to match="genres".  But it wont fire!  Nothing I do makes the genres template do anything.  My output duplicates the whole input xml.  I'm not concerned with getting the real genre data from another file until I can get the genres template to do something.

Comment: I've just noticed you said the input XML shown was "partial". Perhaps you left out the important bits, like the namespace declarations?

Answer (score 1):

`match="entry[genres]"` means that the matched element
is `entry` with `genres` inside.

So this template processes the whole `entry` element (not `genres`).

And what is the result?
I made a test using your XML and XSLT and got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    Genre data goes here
```

So this template outputs just its content,
instead of the whole source, and the identity template has no chance
to process anything.

Probably you should write `match="entry/genres"`.
Or maybe just `match="genres"` would be enough?

### Edit

The real cause why your template did not work was that you forgot
about namespace issues, namely the `namespace` declaration in the
root tag.

It causes that:

- all your tags are in the above mentioned namespace, not in the
  default (empty) namespace,
- your template tried to match `genres` element **in the empty
  namespace**.

So you can leave attributes in your source XML, including `namespace`,
but make the following changes in your XSLT:

- The `stylesheet` tag must contain declaration of this namespace
  with some prefix, e.g. `xmlns:tel="http://periapsis.org/tellico/"`.
- The `match` attribute in your template must refer to just this
  namespace, i.e. include the above prefix:
  `<xsl:template match="tel:genres"/>`.

As far as the `DOCTYPE` row is concerned:

Using *xsltransform.net* I tried to include this row in the source XML
but got the following error:

```
Error on line 1 column 2 of http://periapsis.org/:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The markup declarations
  contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must
  be well-formed.
```

Probably the reason is inaccessibility or some errors in the referred *.dtd* file.
So I agree with you, that this row should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed it to just "genres" and then tried "entry/genres" and even made that an empty template expecting the genre elements to be removed and Nothing happens! It appears the genres template is not being seen by the processor.

Comment: I've just noticed you said the input XML shown was "partial". Perhaps you left out the important bits, like the namespace declarations?